# Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED? installation failed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am developing a small application that lists data from mysql sever But I'm getting the below error while i'm trying to run the code.

Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED

Please can any one help me to sort out this error.

```html
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.kosalgeek.android.androidphpmysql">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="@android:icon">
        <activity
            android:name=".ListActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_list"

            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
               />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DetailActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_detail"
            android:parentActivityName=".ListActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.kosalgeek.android.androidphpmysql.ListActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".InsertActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_insert"
            android:parentActivityName=".ListActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.kosalgeek.android.androidphpmysql.ListActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try 
1) removing all `android:parentActivityName=".ListActivity"` attributes

2) removing all

```
<meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.kosalgeek.android.androidphpmysql.ListActivity" />
```

Comment: i tried the second solution nd it works very well , thnx (y)